# How to make inline property check to return boolean?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I have a function:

```
function test(obj?: { someProperty: string}) {
  return obj && obj.someProperty;
}
```

My assumption was, that the return value of this function is a boolean (As *WebStorm* tells me). But the *TypeScript* compiler complaines about the return value is ether `undefined | string`.

**My question**

How to I write a proper inline property check in TypeScript, which really return a boolean in any case?

I could write:

```
function test(obj?: { someProperty: string}) {
  return !!(obj && obj.someProperty);
}
```

But this seems to be a bit uncomfortable to some people.

Comment: if you only want to check whether the property exists, then `!!(obj && obj.someProperty)` is a valid solution, personally I would prefer `!!obj && !!obj.someProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this solution:

```
function test(obj?: { someProperty: string}) {
  return obj && obj.someProperty && true || false;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But like `!!` somehow hard to read for none JavaScript advanced users.

Comment: this might also return `undefined` of obj failes.

Comment: So you can use this: obj != null && obj.hasOwnProperty("someProperty")

Comment: It's getting worse :P

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your return value to [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Boolean) :

```
function test(obj?: { someProperty: string}) {
  return Boolean(obj && obj.someProperty);
}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/oq4jr518/

Comment: I think the right end to *start from* is to add `boolean` as the return type (`function test(...) : boolean {`). Then either this cast or `!!`.

Comment: @SamiHult adding boolean as return type does not work, because `undefined is not assignable to boolean`

Comment: @SamiHult I'm not sure that adding a return type would suffice to resolve the issue.

Comment: No, adding return type will not solve the problem, that's why I wrote it as a comment. And no, I did not downvote, I think this is a way to solve the problem.

Comment: `return Boolean(obj && obj.someProperty);` is the same as `return !!(obj && obj.someProperty);`, so this does not actually help, since this is already stated in the question

Comment: @NikitaMalyschkin the question stated `this seems to be a bit uncomfortable to some people`, not that it doesn't work. So I gave a better/another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` operator does not implicitly cast into boolean. What actually happens:

```
A && B && C
// if A is falsy return A
// else return B && C
//      if B is falsy return B
//      else return C
```

in your case you have three possibilities:

1. obj is undefined -> returns undefined
2. obj is defined but `someProperty` is undefined -> returns undefined
3. obj is defined and`someProperty` is defined -> returns some property (in this case string)

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I didn't know that (even though the return type of my function is telling exactly that ;) )

Comment: @SamiHult true, but it's a useful information anyway and helps understanding the core problem.

Comment: @SamiHult no, its not the answer. But it's the information he needs to solve his problem. Give a man a fish...

Comment: Same answer I would have given, just add that the simplest way to get around this is the way he already found, use `!!`. Typescript models the exact behavior of JS, so it is right to say `obj && obj.someProperty` is `undefined | string`